# Add Company field to Customers Tab in the BackOffice

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I'm running prestashop 1.4.8.3 and I've tried the following modification on AdminCustomers.php

```
     $this->_select = '(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-YEAR(`birthday`)) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_DATE, 5)<RIGHT(`birthday`, 5)) as age, (
            SELECT c.date_add FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'guest g
            LEFT JOIN ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'connections c ON c.id_guest = g.id_guest
            WHERE g.id_customer = a.id_customer
            ORDER BY c.date_add DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ) as connect';

// This is new code
$this->_select = '(SELECT d.company FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'address d WHERE d.id_customer = a.id_customer LIMIT 1) as company';

// LH company name
$genders = array(
    1 => $this->l('M'),
    2 => $this->l('F'),
    9 => $this->l('?'));
$this->fieldsDisplay = array(
    'id_customer' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('ID'),
        'align' => 'center',
        'width' => 25),
    'id_gender' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('Gender'),
        'width' => 25,
        'align' => 'center',
        'icon' => array(
            1 => 'male.gif',
            2 => 'female.gif',
            'default' => 'unknown.gif'),
        'orderby' => false,
        'type' => 'select',
        'select' => $genders,
        'filter_key' => 'a!id_gender'),
    'lastname' => array('title' => $this->l('Last Name'), 'width' => 80),
    'firstname' => array('title' => $this->l('First name'), 'width' => 60),
    'email' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('E-mail address'),
        'width' => 120,
        'maxlength' => 19),
    'company' => array('title' => $this->l('Company'), 'width' => 60),
    'age' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('Age'),
        'width' => 30,
        'search' => false),
    'active' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('Enabled'),
        'width' => 25,
        'align' => 'center',
        'active' => 'status',
        'type' => 'bool',
        'orderby' => false),
    'newsletter' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('News.'),
        'width' => 25,
        'align' => 'center',
        'type' => 'bool',
        'callback' => 'printNewsIcon',
        'orderby' => false),
    'optin' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('Opt.'),
        'width' => 25,
        'align' => 'center',
        'type' => 'bool',
        'callback' => 'printOptinIcon',
        'orderby' => false),
    'date_add' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('Registration'),
        'width' => 30,
        'type' => 'date',
        'align' => 'right'),
    'connect' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('Connection'),
        'width' => 60,
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'search' => false));
```

The weird thing is that it seems to work, but only for one or two browser refreshes, afterward it fails displaying an SQL fail message.

Any idea that would put me on the right track would be highly appreciated.

Comment: And what would this SQL fail message say..?

Comment: Nothing specific, just a vague fail message.

Answer (score 0):

You may try it:

```
// This is new code
$this->_select .= ', (SELECT d.company FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'address d WHERE d.id_customer = a.id_customer LIMIT 1) as company';
```

Also you may see your sql-query here:
`AdminTab::getList()` on line `$this->_list = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);`

Comment: Didn't work, same error. I'm not sure what you meant by "you may see your sql query here". Care to rephrase please?

Comment: It's difficult to solve the issue not understanding what's wrong with your SQL requiest. The place where CMS makes a request to db in this case is the AdminTab.php class in getList() function. The request text is in the $sql variable. If you give an example of SQL-request and the error message it will be easier to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try show sql debug on open file `config` > `config.inc.php` and set true `define('_PS_DEBUG_SQL_', false)`. You will notice error syntax sql. 
Don't forget to try modify your code

> $temp = '(SELECT d.company FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'address d WHERE
>   d.id_customer = a.id_customer LIMIT 1) as company';
>
> var_dump(Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql));

Last, run your code, you will found what the error :)